# Disable the button after clicking using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, opencart2.x

I am working on opencart. I dont want my users to buy multiple products they can buy only 1 product with 1 customer id, so for this i want my add to cart button to help me. I want this button to be disabled (read only) if add to cart process is performed successfully.

HTML:

```
 <button type="button" id="button-cart" data-loading-text="<?php echo $text_loading; ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"><?php echo $button_cart; ?></button>
```

Jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$('#button-cart').on('click', function() {
$.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
    type: 'post',
    data: $('#product input[type=\'text\'], #product input[type=\'hidden\'], #product input[type=\'radio\']:checked, #product input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, #product select, #product textarea'),
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function() {
        $('#button-cart').button('loading');
    },
    complete: function() {
        $('#button-cart').button('reset');
    },
    success: function(json) {
        $('.alert, .text-danger').remove();
        $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');

        if (json['error']) {
            if (json['error']['option']) {
                for (i in json['error']['option']) {
                    var element = $('#input-option' + i.replace('_', '-'));

                    if (element.parent().hasClass('input-group')) {
                        element.parent().after('<div class="text-danger">' + json['error']['option'][i] + '</div>');
                    } else {
                        element.after('<div class="text-danger">' + json['error']['option'][i] + '</div>');
                    }
                }
            }

            if (json['error']['recurring']) {
                $('select[name=\'recurring_id\']').after('<div class="text-danger">' + json['error']['recurring'] + '</div>');
            }

            // Highlight any found errors
            $('.text-danger').parent().addClass('has-error');
        }

        if (json['success']) {
            $('.breadcrumb').after('<div class="alert alert-success">' + json['success'] + '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');

            $('#cart > button').html('<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> ' + json['total']);

            $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');

            $('#cart > ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');
        }
    }
});
});//--></script>
```

I know this will do the trick

```
$(this).attr('disabled', true);
```

But iam not finding the best position for it. I want the button to be disabled if the validation is all done and product is entered in cart area

Comment: with this `jQuery` approach, button will be disabled only one time. If end user refresh the page OR move to different page and come back; he/she will be able to see button in `enabled` state.

Comment: @vijayP than which approach will be fine if its disabled for current user if he has added product in cart?

Comment: You will have to use `jQuery` approach as well as server side validation to achieve your goal. For example - while rendering the page; at the time of button creation, there has to be a server side code's `if` condition to check whether current product is present in cart or not. If it is there then instead of "Add" button, show dummy disabled Add button having no click event. Secondly use above code to have `ajax` for add to cart and in `success` handler instead of disabling the button, I will suggest to replace original button with dummy button with no click event.

Comment: @vijayP waow sounds very great..

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery.attr()**

```
Get the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of matched elements.
```

whereas,

**jQuery.prop()**

```
Get the value of a property for the first element in the set of matched elements.
```

Before jQuery 1.6 , the attr() method sometimes took property values into account when retrieving some attributes, which caused in inconsistent behavior. And thus, the prop() method was introduced. As of jQuery 1.6. , the .prop() method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while .attr() retrieves attributes.

According to your code you are highlighting error by `$('.text-danger').parent().addClass('has-error');`. So
you can use `prop('disabled', true)` instead of  `$(this).attr('disabled', true);` and add it to just after `$('.text-danger').parent().addClass('has-error');`

```
 $('.text-danger').parent().addClass('has-error');
 $(this).prop('disabled', true)
```

Comment: i know that but where to use it in the jquery code mentioned above that is my question?

Comment: ya, but you aren't answering question

Comment: @urfusion it didnt work i added $(this).prop('disabled', true); after the code where u said still it was enabled after click

Comment: there is no error in console if  i set a alert here its executing but not the code..

Comment: why are we entering this in this if (json['error']) condition. if everything goes fine than it wont execute thats y its not executing

Comment: According to your code you are highlighting error by `$('.text-danger').parent().addClass('has-error');` so button should be disable only when we are getting errors. that's by I suggest you to put the code after `$('.text-danger').parent().addClass('has-error');`.

Comment: and you didn't put any return statement in your code so your code execution will not stop even after producing the errors.

Comment: this wont do the trick than :( as there will be no errors. As its opencart by default jquery so its not my fault.

Comment: put a `console.log` just after you highlighting errors and check you console.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are relying on the response from your service call to validate success or error.

In that case it will be better to disable the button as soon as your service is called, and wait for response.

After response if your validation is successful, then no worries, else re-enable button and notify user the error and ask to make changes if required.

So the code could be like this,

```
$('#button-cart').on('click', function() {
        var _button_ref = this;
                $(_button_ref).attr('disabled', true);
                $.ajax({
                url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
                        type: 'post',
                        data: $('#product input[type=\'text\'], #product input[type=\'hidden\'], #product input[type=\'radio\']:checked, #product input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, #product select, #product textarea'),
                        dataType: 'json',
                        beforeSend: function() {
                        $('#button-cart').button('loading');
                        },
                        complete: function() {
                        $('#button-cart').button('reset');
                        },
                        success: function(json) {
                        $('.alert, .text-danger').remove();
                                $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
                                if (json['error']) {
                        // your logic
                        $(_button_ref).attr('disabled', 'false');
                        }

                        if (json['success']) {
                        // your logic
                        }
                        }
                });
```

Also, it will be better if you have error call back function, to handle if service fails.